# Reset Count - If different value in specific column using C# lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Is there a way to reset count after select? Here is sample in [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3otZMh).

This is the result I'm getting,

```
{groupRowId: 1, monthYear: '2020-08', projectName: 'Project 1'}
{groupRowId: 2, monthYear: '2020-08', projectName: 'Project 2'}
{groupRowId: 3, monthYear: '2020-08', projectName: 'Project 3'}
{groupRowId: 4, monthYear: '2021-08', projectName: 'Project 4'}
{groupRowId: 5, monthYear: '2021-08', projectName: 'Project 5'}
{groupRowId: 6, monthYear: '2021-08', projectName: 'Project 6'}
```

This is what I've tried.

```
public List<object> GenerateDynamicCalendar(List<ProjectResult> result) {
            int row = 1;
     var queryAug = result.Where(c => c.LiveDate != Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000") && c.LiveDate.Month == 8)
              .GroupBy(c => new { c.Month, c.Name})
              .Select(g => new DynamicProjectCalendarAug
              {
                  GroupRowId = row++,
                  MonthYear = g.Key.Month,
                  ProjectName = g.Key.Name,
                  Aug = g.Where(c => c.LiveDate != Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01 00:00:00.000") && c.LiveDate.Month == 8).Max(c => c.Name)
              }).ToList();
        
            List<object> query = otherMonthResult.Cast<object>()
                .Concat(queryAug)
            return query;
    }
```

And this is what I want to achieve. Since **MonthYear** value is different I want to reset count back to 1

```
{groupRowId: 1, monthYear: '2020-08', projectName: 'Project 1'}
{groupRowId: 2, monthYear: '2020-08', projectName: 'Project 2'}
{groupRowId: 3, monthYear: '2020-08', projectName: 'Project 3'}
{groupRowId: 1, monthYear: '2021-08', projectName: 'Project 4'}
{groupRowId: 2, monthYear: '2021-08', projectName: 'Project 5'}
{groupRowId: 3, monthYear: '2021-08', projectName: 'Project 6'}
```

Comment: What type is `result` a collection of?

Comment: I don't think your GroupBy works as `Name` doesn't exist in (group) Key and also I believe you should perform GroupBy Month only.

Comment: Can you give more information about your input? What items does the result list have that gives you the result you showed us? Maybe you can even give it as C# code instead of JSON, because this helps us to copy-paste the input and directly work with it.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry.. I edit my post just now.

Comment: _"I want to reset count back to 1"_ - I don't see `count` in your code _anywhere_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you group by only month, you could use the [`.GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-groupby-3(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1))-system-func((-1-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-2))-system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-1))))'s `resultSelector` to create a `DynamicProjectCalendarAug` object for each group item. The `resultSelector` takes advantage of the [`.Select()` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-select-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-int32-1)))) that provides the index of the source element. It would look like the following:

```csharp
var queryAug = result
    //.Where( ... )
    .GroupBy(
        resultItem => resultItem.Month,
        ( _, itemsInMonth ) => itemsInMonth
             .Select(( item, i ) => new DynamicProjectCalendarAug {
                 GroupRowId = i + 1,
                 MonthYear = item.Month,
                 ProjectName = item.Name,
                 //Aug = ...
             }))
    .SelectMany(_ => _)
    .ToList();
```

For a simplified implementation of your classes, this example input:

```csharp
List<ProjectResult> result = new()
{
    new() { Month = "2020-08", Name = "Project 1"},
    new() { Month = "2020-08", Name = "Project 2"},
    new() { Month = "2020-08", Name = "Project 3"},
    new() { Month = "2021-08", Name = "Project 4"},
    new() { Month = "2021-08", Name = "Project 5"},
    new() { Month = "2021-08", Name = "Project 6"}
};
```

will have the following output:

```csharp
1  |  2020-08  |  Project 1
2  |  2020-08  |  Project 2
3  |  2020-08  |  Project 3
1  |  2021-08  |  Project 4
2  |  2021-08  |  Project 5
3  |  2021-08  |  Project 6
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ehpbgV).

Answer (score 0):

Created an example to show how you can solve this.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/b9mnau

Answer (score 0):

Having

```
record WithRowId(int GroupRowId, MyDto MyDto);
record MyDto(int X, string Val);

var list = new []{ 
    new MyDto(X: 1, Val: "a"),
    new MyDto(X: 1, Val: "b"),
    new MyDto(X: 2, Val: "c"),
    new MyDto(X: 2, Val: "d"),
};
```

you could add group row id the following ways:

```
var list2 = new List<WithRowId>();
foreach( var group in list.GroupBy( c => c.X ))
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach(var r in group)
    {
        list2.Add(new WithRowId(1 + i++, r));
    }
}


// Method 2
var list2B = list
 .GroupBy( c => c.X)
 .SelectMany( g => g.Select((x, i) => new WithRowId(GroupRowId: i+1, MyDto: x)));
```

The second method uses the lesser known variant of `Select` which provides an index.